# What happens with event handlers when an object goes out of scope?

Tags: c#, .net, events, scope

Let's say we have the following setup:

```
public class ClassA
{
   public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
}

public class ClassB : IDisposable
{
   public void SomeMethod(ClassA value)
   {
      value.SomeEvent += (s, e) => { DoSomething(); };
   }

   void DoSomething() { }

   void Dispose() { }
}

public static class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
      var a = new ClassA();

      using (var b = new ClassB())
         b.SomeMethod(a);

      // POINT OF QUESTION!!
   }
}
```

What happens when the event `SomeEvent` is raised after the "POINT OF QUESTION"?

Comment: Is this C#, .Net? I went ahead and added those tags ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will call method of disposed object. That's why it is important to unsubscribe. It even can lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Won't this just toss a run-time error?  (Null pointer reference or some such).

Comment: @Hogan Disposing is not equal to being garbage collected. In this case `b` will never be garbage collected because there's still a reference to it in `a`'s event (exactly the problem). If `b`'s implementation is correct it will throw a `ObjectDisposedException`, though.

Comment: @Jouke - I guess I'm wondering if the thunk will point to null.  I guess there is no way for this to happen -- if just feels like it should.

Comment: @Hogan only if the Dispose method is implemented correctly and it unsubscribes from the event. Otherwise `b` will not be null until whatever `a` points to gets collected (causing `b` to be collected as well).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Dispose()` method of ClassB to unsubscribe from the ClassA event. You run the risk of classes not being garbage collected which of course leads to potential memory leaks. You should **always** unsub from events.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you have above would unhook your event handler. Since both `a` and `b` go out of scope at the same time, you'd be safe. Since `a` and `b` can both be collected, then `a` will not keep `b` alive.

If you were to raise the `ClassA.SomeEvent` event after your using statement, then `ClassB.DoSomething` will be called even though `b` has been disposed. You would have to explicitly remove the event handler in this case.

If you were to retain a reference to `a` somewhere else, then `b` would be keep alive by `a`. Again, because the event handler has not been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. Runtime doesn't know about `Dispose` method and call to this method inside using statement do nothing to memory management.

Garbage collection is all about memory management, but `IDisposable` (and `Finalizer`) is about resource management, so you still should think yourself and implement it manually (and propertly, for example unsubscribe in `Dispose`).